# How to run subtitles in video using video.js for Opera, Chrome?

Tags: video.js

I wrote code to insert subtitles in the video

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>name</title>

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "skript/video-js.min.css" />
    <script src = "skript/video.min.js"> </script>

    </head> 
<body>
<video
  class="video-js"
  controls
  preload="auto"
  width="640"
  height="264"
  data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    <track label="rus" kind="subtitles" srclang="ru" src="sub/rus.vtt"/>
    <track label="eng" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="sub/eng.vtt"/>

  </video>
</body>


</html>
```

But it does not work with browsers Opera, Chrome
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to embed vtt/subtitles files in m3u8 package? It works with all browsers.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not fully understand you
m3u8 is a video library. how is it related to subtitles?
Do you suggest converting vtt  in m3u8?

Comment: Hi @zeni1agent, m3u8 is metadata file for streaming video (you are already using it under the hood, check urk in browser network). All stream urls are stored in this file and thats how player understand which segment to pull to play. Ref : [https://www.lifewire.com/m3u8-file-2621956]

M3U8 can also contains metadata abt subtitles, so you have to just append your vtt file url in this file appropriately (sequence of reference is also important).
Please search for "how to include subtile (vtt) files in m3u8"